# How to design the data that you gathered from the table

Tags: php, html, css

I've printed all the data from the database, but my main problem is how to design my data.

I have a table named `post_tbl` and columns(`post_id`,`post_message`,`post_date`)

this is my query:

```
$query = "SELECT `post_id`,`post_message` FROM `post_tbl` ORDER BY `post_date`;
```

This is how I print in php:

```
if($query_run = mysql_query($query))
{
    while($query_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_run))
    {
        $ex_post_id = $query_row['post_id'];
        $ex_post_message = $query_row['user_name'];
        $ex_post_date= $query_row['post_date'];

        echo $ex_post_message;
    }
}
```

how do I make my `ex_post_message` have a unfirom border and width using html and css? pls help. thanks

Comment: StackOverflow isn't a design or code-writing service.

Comment: You can echo $ex_post_message inside td's to achieve this

Comment: I'm not asking for the code though, I'm just asking for the concept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can echo HTML element like:

```
 echo "<div class='classname1'>" . $ex_post_message . "</div>";
```

Then the class classname1 should handle the design. Like the following:

```
<style>
.classname1{
   width: 100px;
   height: 30px;
   border: 1px solid blackl
}
</style>
```

There are many ways to achieve this. The one that I've provided is just an example.

Comment: Yes, study more about CSS for better design. Remember that you can render all HTML elements in PHP using echo.

Comment: i didn't know that you can add class attribute while echoing a variable. thanks sir i'll keep that in mind.

Comment: Yes. Just pay attention on the concatenation. See on how did I put $ex_post_message in the echo. The class attribute on the other hand has single quotation because I've used double quotation first. Goodluck!

Answer (score 1):

```
    if($query_run = mysql_query($query))
    {
        while($query_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_run))
        {

           $arrMaster[] =   $ex_post_message;

        }
    }

foreach ($arrMaster as $key => $value) 
    {
      if($i==0)
      {
       $table1.="<tr>";
    foreach ($value as $keyc => $valuec) 
                 {
                     $table1.="<th>".$keyc."</th>";
                 }
           $table1.="</tr>";
           $i=1;
           } 
            $table1.="<tr>";   

                foreach ($value as $keyc => $valuec) 
                  {
                   $table1.="<td>".$valuec."</td>";
                  }
             $table1.="</tr>";
    }

    $table1 .= "</table>";


    echo $table1;
```

at this way you can add any style to your table or any class

Comment: It's not the answer that i'm looking for. but thanks for your effort, I really appreciate it :)